# Find all elements that have a certain data attribute (regardless of value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal, jquery-traversing

I have a form with a bunch of text elements, some of which have a data attribute set.

I want to loop through all the elements that have that attribute, extracting the attribute.

I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jdege/qG6kz/1/).

```
var textInputs = $(':text');
alert('found ' + textInputs.length + ' textInputs');

var datas = textInputs.find('[data-foo]');
alert('found ' + datas.length + ' datas');
```

I'm finding the text elements, but my selector on the data attribute is returning no elements.

Ideas would be helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[data-foo]` selector is correct, but you should use it in a [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), instead of in a [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var datas = textInputs.filter('[data-foo]');
```

[**See working fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2LfVP/)

Comment: That seems to work. But I'll need to read up on the difference between find() and filter().  Thanks.

Comment: To elaborate, just using the `[data-foo]` selector would mean EVERY single DOM element would have to be checked for it, quite a tedious task. Filtering down beforehand with something that can be done with a native function (like `getElementsByTagName`) is much more performant. `$('input').filter('[data-foo]')` instead of `$('[data-foo]')`.

Comment: Performance wise, wouldn't $(':text[data-foo]'); be faster? Or equivalent?

Comment: @Bonatoc You are right, `$(':text[data-foo]');` is faster [(see this fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/x6YeT/). Additionally, there is an even more efficient way: `$('[type="text"][data-foo]');`. It is also described in the [`:text` jquery selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) that the `[type="text"]` is better but don't match the `<input>` with no type attribute.

Comment: @JeffDege I'm glad to hear that you'll seek for further knowledge! That's the most important part. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/qjb3V/

```
     var datas = $(':text[data-foo]');
```